# Creating a new list by extracting first and last element of a nested list in python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I want to extract first and last elements form a nested list and create a new list from that. This is my code.
Expected result should be **[True, False, 'a', 'z']**, however the output I get is **[[True, False], ['a', 'z']]**
Any insight on how to correct this, so that my output is a new list?

```
def first_and_last(l):
    result = []
    for x in l:
        result.append([x[0], x[-1]])
    return result

fl = first_and_last([[True, True, False], ['a', 'b', 'z']])
print(fl)
```

Comment: `result.append([x[0], x[-1]])` here you are appending an `list`. Instead extend (use `extend` in place of `append`) the result or append both element separately and not as a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of appending, extension of string shall work;

```
def first_and_last(l):
    result = []
    for x in l:
        # result = result + [x[0], x[-1]]
        result.extend((x[0], x[-1]))          # This one is faster than + sign extension of list
    return result

fl = first_and_last([[True, True, False], ['a', 'b', 'z']])
print(fl)

# [True, False, 'a', 'z']
```

Comment: To decrease object churn `extend` is probably a better fit: `result.extend((x[0], x[-1]))` (the second pair of `()` is necessary btw)

Comment: Thank you very much. Out of curiosity is there also a way to do it with append or not?

Comment: Glad to help... Thanks @RobinGugel for your input... (Edited the code)... & I think if you wanna use append, then maybe can use it like two times for first & last items... like result.append(x[0]) & in next line result.append(x[-1])... Drop a like & accept the best answer that works for your problem statement... To grow & motivate community... Happy Coding :)